# Show the Christoffel symbol satisfy this condition

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

$$\Gamma^{\mu}_{\mu v} = \frac{\partial_{v}(|g|)^{0.5}}{(|g|)^{0.5}}$$

I am trying to show this equality, but I'm only getting through:

$ \Gamma^{\mu}_{\mu v} = 0.5*[g^{\mu\mu}(\partial_{v} g_{\mu \mu}) + g^{\mu v}(\partial_{\mu} g_{vv})] $

I would appreciate any tip to go on

Comment: Hint: the christoffel symbols can be related to the derivative of a basis; the metric can be written also in terms of the dot product of the basis.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A helpful proof in contracting the Christoffel symbol?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/309535/)

Comment: $g^{\mu\mu}(\partial_{v} g_{\mu \mu}) + g^{\mu v}(\partial_{\mu} g_{vv})$ In tensor calculus, you can’t have expressions with 4 $\mu$’s or 3 $\nu$’s, so what you’ve done is ncorrect.