# Contraction of Christoffel symbol and metric tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

How can I prove this contraction of Christoffel symbol with metric tensor?
$$
g^{k\ell} \Gamma^i_{\ \ k\ell} = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{|g|}}\frac{\partial\left(\sqrt{|g|}g^{ik}\right)}{\partial x^k}
$$
I know the relation for the Christoffel symbol contracted with itself and this one is similar, but I cannot find the clue.

I start from the definition of gamma:
$$
g^{k\ell} \Gamma^i_{\ \ k\ell} = \frac{1}{2}g^{kl}g^{ij}(\partial_k g_{jl} + \partial_l g_{jk} - \partial_j g_{kl}) =
 \frac{1}{2}g^{ij}(2g^{kl}\partial_k g_{jl} - g^{kl}\partial_j g_{kl}) 
$$
Now I can see that I can use the relation for derivative of det(g) in the second term in bracket, but don't know what to do with the first term.

Comment: Hi! It'd be useful to see what calculations you've tried so far and where you've struggled. The method is almost identical to the other case https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/309535/a-helpful-proof-in-contracting-the-christoffel-symbol

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Note that we use MathJax to typeset mathematics; you can find a good tutorial [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020). I've transcribed your image, but in future you should typeset it yourself. (As a good starting point, you can often copy-paste directly from Wikipedia and then trim the results.)

Comment: That said, please take a minute to read our [guidelines for homework and exercise questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714) as well as [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093). We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and we prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: Work out the RHS first. Do you know how to take the derivative of a determinant?

Answer (score 1):

The most important point about this computation is to use the formula for the derivative of the metric determinant
$$\frac{\partial_i g}{g} = g^{jk} \partial_i g_{jk} $$
The derivation of this identity can be found in the answer to [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/249961/why-is-the-covariant-derivative-of-the-determinant-of-the-metric-zero). You can then derive the relationship between $g^{ij}{}_{,k}$ and $g_{ij,k}$ by taking a derivative of $\delta^i{}_{j} = g^{ik}g_{kj}$. Finally, you take the formula for the Christoffel symbols in terms of metric derivatives and after some algebra you get the result!