# An equation about Christoffel connection

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

In Sean Carroll's GR book, page 101, he says that

> It is straightforward to show that the Christoffel connection satisfies
> $$
> \Gamma^{\mu}_{\mu\lambda}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\left | g \right |}}\partial_{\lambda}\sqrt{\left | g \right |}.
> $$

I don't understand how this is straightforward. Can someone give a clue?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/309535/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite immediate to see that when you write explicitly the definition for the Christoffel symbols, when contracting the first indices, you will obtain the following form:
$$
\Gamma^\mu_{\mu\nu}=\dfrac{1}{2}g^{\mu\sigma}\partial_\nu g_{\mu\sigma}=\dfrac{1}{2}\text{tr}(g^{-1}\partial_\nu g)
$$

Now, the following matrix identity can be exploited:
$$
\text{tr}(\ln A)=\ln(\text{det}A)
$$

Furthermore, if A turns out to be differentiable, then
$$
\dfrac{d}{d\lambda}\ln(\text{det}A)=\text{tr}\left(A^{-1}\dfrac{d}{d\lambda}A\right)
$$

so that at the end:
$$
\Gamma^\mu_{\mu\nu}=\dfrac{1}{2}\partial_\nu \ln(\text{det} \,g)=\partial_\nu \ln\sqrt{|{g|}}
$$

Answer (score 2):

The christoffel symbols are defined by
\begin{align*}
\Gamma^\rho_{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2}g^{\rho\lambda}\Big(\partial_\mu g_{\nu\lambda} + \partial_\nu g_{\mu\lambda} - \partial_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}\Big)
\end{align*}
In the sought after expression we sum over $\mu$ i.e.
\begin{align*}
\Gamma^\mu_{\mu\nu} &= \frac{1}{2}g^{\mu\lambda}\Big(\partial_\mu g_{\nu\lambda} + \partial_{\nu} g_{\mu\lambda} - \partial_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}\Big) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\Big(\partial^\lambda g_{\lambda\nu} + g^{\mu\lambda} \partial_\nu g_{\mu\lambda} - \partial^{\mu} g_{\mu\nu}\Big) \\
&= \frac{1}{2} g^{\mu\lambda}\,\partial_\nu\, g_{\mu\lambda} 
\end{align*}
Now note that the derivative of a determinant is given by $\delta g = g\, g^{\mu\nu}\delta g_{\mu\nu}$ (see 4.68 p 163 in Carroll) Where we choose $x^\mu \to x^\mu + \varepsilon^\mu$ st. $g_{\mu\nu}(x) \to g_{\mu\nu}(x + \varepsilon) = g_{\mu\nu}(x) + \varepsilon^{\lambda}\partial_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}(x) + \mathcal{O}(\varepsilon^2)$ so we see that $\delta g_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}$ (and similarly for the determinant). So we can express the derivative of the metric as $\partial_\lambda g  = g\, g^{\mu\nu}\partial_\lambda g_{\mu\nu}$, which we then plug into the formula above
\begin{align*}
\Gamma^\mu_{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2g} \partial_\lambda g = \frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\partial_\lambda \sqrt{g}
\end{align*}