# Christoffel symbol and metric tensor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

In B. Schutz's book *A First Course in General Relativity*, I read on the page 152:

> $$ \Gamma^\alpha{}_{\mu \alpha} = \frac{1}{2} g^{\alpha \beta} g_{\alpha \beta, \mu} \tag{6.38} $$
> Since $\left(g^{\alpha \beta}\right)$ is the inverse matrix of
> $\left(g_{\alpha \beta}\right)$, it can be shown (see Exer. 7, $\S
>  6.9$ ) that the derivative of the determinant $g$ of the matrix $\left(g_{\alpha \beta}\right)$ is:
> $$ g_{, \mu}=g g^{\alpha \beta} g_{\beta \alpha, \mu} \tag{6.39} $$
> Using this in Eq. (6.38), we find:
> $$ \Gamma^\alpha{}_{\mu \alpha}=(\sqrt{-g})_{, \mu} / \sqrt{-g} \tag{6.40}$$

Where does the square root come from in the Eq. 6.40?

Using Eq. (6.39) in Eq. (6.38), we just find:

$$ \Gamma^\alpha{}_{\mu \alpha}=\frac{1}{2} g_{, \mu} / g $$

Perhaps I am missing some obvious facts. Nevertheless, if someone would be so kind to explain to me, I would appreciate greatly.

Comment: I think in this case it is a matter of taste or notation wether to use the from in terms of $\sqrt{-g}$ or the one you derived just in terms of $g$: they are equivalent which you can check by using the chain rule in Eq. (6.40). $\sqrt{-g}$ is usually used or appears due to its appearance in the volume element.

Comment: Well, you have the identity log (√g) =(1/2) log g

Comment: Compute the derivative in (6.40), it gives your final equation on the first step, so you can work backwards from your final equation to (6.40) in one line. I added an answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/777426/25851) related to your question that you might find helpful.

Comment: I assume that you mean $g_{,\mu}$ in your last equation and not $g_{\mu}$, right?

Comment: Is $\sqrt{}-g$ supposed to be $\sqrt{-g}$ (`\sqrt{}-g` vs `\sqrt{-g}`)? The formatting as it currently is written is quite off-putting.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert, I apologize for mistyping. You are correct, I've amended the original question. Thank you

Comment: @KyleKanos, yes, I assume, it is \sqrt{-g}. Mathpix recognized it is that way (in the book it is √−; but I think it is just a typing peculiarity). Perhaps I should correct that before posting. Thank you

Comment: The more obvious RHS for Eq. (6.40) would be $g_\mu/(2g)$, which can be rewritten as $\sqrt{|g|}_\mu/\sqrt{|g|}$. If $g<0$, as happens e.g. in $-+\cdots$ (as well as $+-\cdots$ if the spacetime dimension is even, such as in our $n=4$ experience), this is $\sqrt{-g}_\mu/\sqrt{-g}$.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/309535/2451 and links therein.

Comment: @N0va, I've got it now. Very appreciated!!!

Comment: Explanation with chain rule. $$g = -\left(\sqrt{-g}\right)^2$$ Differentiating both sides with respect to μ, we get: $$g_{, \mu} = -2\sqrt{-g} (\sqrt{-g})_{, \mu}$$ Substituting it into $$ \Gamma^\alpha{}_{\mu \alpha}=\frac{1}{2} g_{, \mu} / g $$ Finally getting $$\Gamma^\alpha{}_{\mu \alpha} = \frac{(\sqrt{-g})_{, \mu}}{\sqrt{-g}} \tag{6.40}$$